# Select Certain Groups while Excluding Others

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've made a small dataset similar to what I need.  It has the following:

```
ID  Color
2   blue
2   red
3   blue
3   yellow
4   white
4   green
4   blue
5   green
5   purple
5   black
```

I want to select the grouped IDs but exclude those that contain 'white' or 'black'.  So, in other words, IDs 2 and 3 should show.  But 4 and 5 should not show because they have 'white' and/or 'black' within their Color column.

Comment: Have you attempted any of this using SQL? I would suggest for future questions at least showing what code you attempted.

Comment: The code from Simon and Juergen both work.  Thank you very much.  Thanks also to Fiddle and Satwik.  I very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Sum up how many times these forbidden value appear in your groups. Select only the ones where this sum is zero

```
select id
from your_table
group by id
having sum(case when color in ('white','black') then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM colortable
WHERE ID NOT IN (
    SELECT ID
    FROM colortable
    WHERE Color IN ('white', 'black')  
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT     DISTINCT ID
FROM       TABLE
WHERE      Color NOT IN ('white', 'black')
```

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.ID
FROM @TABLE t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1 
                  FROM @TABLE
                  WHERE t.ID = ID 
                   AND (color = 'white' or color = 'Black') 
                  )
GROUP BY t.ID
```

### [`WORKING SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81952/5)